# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi not showing available networks

Tags: drivers, 20.04, wireless, network-manager

All of a sudden, this morning I don't have wifi on my laptop. I have a Thinkpad E14.

I don't know what caused this. The *wifi is working, I can turn it on and off, but it searches for available networks and it doesn't find any*. I turned the wifi off and on,`sudo nmcli networking off && sudo nmcli networking on` and `sudo service network-manager` - didn't work.

Kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic

When i go to `Software and Updates > Additional Software` I get "no additional drivers available".

I also updated and upgraded, rebooted but still the same problem.

`lspci` gives `03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961`

More info:

```
$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 88:a4:c2:b2:ce:85
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.186 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:39 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd404000-fd404fff memory:fd400000-fd403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 10:6f:d9:df:16:3d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:60-5f iomemory:60-5f iomemory:60-5f irq:74 memory:670200000-6702fffff memory:670300000-670303fff memory:670304000-670304fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

None of the online fixes helped.

Maybe an update broke it? Maybe the kernel is bad? Maybe I should reinstall it?

### EDIT

Ran the WIFI diagnose script from  WinEunuuchs2Unix's comment: https://pastebin.com/5kALkQi5

Comment: Boot with a live-USB and see if the WiFi works there OK. If it doesn't then reinstalling will simply bring you back to where you are now. Wild Man wrote a script to diagnose WiFi issues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix edited the script output. Don't really know what to look at.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have just re-booted with a ubuntu 20.04 usb on and it worked. I don't know kind of magic happened, but I want to learn more. How could I prevent these wifi problems?

Comment: What about a URL for `sudo dmesg | grep 7921 | nc termbin.com 9999`